# I have tried executing the following NoSQL statement in Microsoft Commos DB but it didn't work

Tags: nosql, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Here is the development environment: Spring Boot, Microsoft Azure Cosmos DB, Java and so on.

The SQL is:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.UnitNumber = "FN8KB1H" AND A.reportTime =
  (SELECT MAX(A.reportTime) FROM A WHERE A.UnitNumber = "FN8KB1H")
```

When I running this SQL, it did execute without exception and return, but nothing, like this "[]". The expected return value is an item, like this:

```
{"id":1, "UnitNumber": "FN8KB1H", "reportTime": "1234567890"}
```

The offical doc is too difficult to understand.What I know is "It does not support uncorrelated subqueries". How can I select the expected return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.UnitNumber = "FN8KB1H" AND A.reportTime =
>   (SELECT MAX(A.reportTime) FROM A WHERE A.UnitNumber = "FN8KB1H")

CosmosDB query does not support uncorrelated subqueries, subqueries can refer to items from the parent collection only. For example:

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    c.id, 
    MaxNutritionValue
FROM c
JOIN (SELECT VALUE Max(n.nutritionValue) FROM n IN c.nutrients) MaxNutritionValue
```

Back to your requirements,please try below sql:

```
SELECT TOP 1 c.id,c.UnitNumber FROM c where c.UnitNumber = "FN8KB1H" ORDER BY c.reportTime DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I would try it tomorrow! May I ask you that where can I learn Cosmos DB easily? It's really difficult to learn it from offical web page, in particular, English words are translated into Chinese.

Comment: @JohnDou I think the original english version is the best way to acquire knowledge about  cosmos db, chinese maybe change it's meanings sometimes. I think if you just want to implement common requirements,the get-started document is enough.